# VMware "boot screen" - add info like contact, phone number, etc.?

Tags: vmware-esxi, vmware-vsphere

I've tried searching Google and VMware's KB but maybe I'm not typing the right search criteria...only finding ways to fix problems with booting or screen issues.

On the default boot screen of a host it looks similar to this picture from GIS:

[image]

I'm curious if it is possible somehow to make it look like this instead (adding custom details):

[image]

I know for the most part the info is "useless" since it is administered remotely, etc.  But when I deploy standalone hosts to branch offices, it'd be nice for them to see this type of info on the boot screen.  I may also include the VMs hosted on it (again on standalone hosts).

Normal monitoring, etc. will be done remotely.  This is strictly for odd times when the branch contact may say "the electricians are saying they need to turn off this circuit but I have no idea who to call in IT to tell them this box needs to be shut down" or similar.  Anyone who has dealt with small branch offices can tell you that if it isn't labeled they easily forget what it is for and will simply say after the incident "I didn't know what it was or who to call."

Possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've always simply used a Post-it note or business card taped to the server chassis with support contacts and instructions. [This works great for telecom equipment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jXlfM.jpg), so it should make sense in your situation, too.

These days, the servers run headless, so there's no boot screen to look at. Especially in the case of ESXi, where *nothing* happens on the screen.

---

However, that doesn't answer your question. You *can* [customize the ESXi welcome screen](http://www.virtuallyghetto.com/2010/09/how-to-add-splash-of-color-to-esxi-dcui.html) by editing `/etc/vmware/welcome`.

[image]

Comment: The host itself is "labeled" with a sticker label with some of these details.  Just curious more than anything at this point.  Don't want to give branch employees any excuses.

Comment: Look at all those zip ties... you should be ashamed.

Comment: Thanks for the answer...I looked at the link and was able to figure it out and get what I was after...no LOLWUT, but close enough!